# Conditional operation with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am writing a program I use Euler's method to understand the behavior of a pendulum.  I can give it a starting condition and run it. But now, I have to do it using a matrix with many starting conditions and during the iteration I have to normalize the value of 'teta' because it must not surpass |2pi| which happens for some conditions that accept the pendulum going all the way through the circle .

```
def pendulo(teta_zero, omega_zero, c_1, c_2, t_total, h_passo):
# inicializações
teta_omega  = np.empty((int(t_total/h_passo)+1, 2))
teta_omega[0][0] = teta_zero
teta_omega[0][1] = omega_zero


#recorrência

for i in range(0, int(t_total/h_passo), 1):
    teta_omega[i+1][0] = ( teta_omega[i][0] ) + ( h_passo*teta_omega[i][1] )
    teta_omega[i+1][1]= teta_omega[i][1] + (h_passo/28)*(forca_teta(teta_omega[i][0], c_1, c_2) - 10*teta_omega[i][1])

    #normalization
    if teta_omega[i+1][0] <= -np.pi:
        teta_omega[i+1][0] = teta_omega[i+1][0] + 2*np.pi

    elif teta_omega[i+1][0] > np.pi:
        teta_omega[i+1][0] = -2*np.pi + teta_omega[i+1][0]
```

My problem is when I try to do it over the matrices I have created with the two starting values using arrays (each dimension is a line of the matrix and each element is a value, one array with 'teta' values and the other with 'omega' values)  because I can't use a similar code because ,as it shows , the value of a matrix seems to be ambigous. I'm just a begginer, I've only had a introductory course in python and I'm learning numpy by myself, can you guys help me do it over a matrix ?

```
def bacias(TH_IT, OM_IT, c_1, c_2, t_total, h_passo):

"""    # inicializações
teta_omega  = np.empty((int(t_total/h_passo)+1, 2))
teta_omega[0][0] = teta_zero
teta_omega[0][1] = omega_zero"""

#recorrência

for i in range(0, int(t_total/h_passo), 1):
    TH_IT = TH_IT + ( h_passo*OM_IT )
    OM_IT = OM_IT + (h_passo/28)*(forca_teta(TH_IT, c_1, c_2) - 10*OM_IT)

    #normalization
    if TH_IT <= -np.pi:
        TH_IT = teta_omega[i+1][0] + 2*np.pi

    elif TH_IT > np.pi:
        TH_IT = -2*np.pi + teta_omega[i+1][0]




return TH_IT, OM_IT
```

This returns me 
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
I hope I've been clear enough, thanks in advance !

Comment: Well the error handling gives you the right answer. You can use .all() or .any() to check if an array is true. Normally you even have a line number to see which array is being checked. If you just want to check if the array is not empty, you can also use len(array)

Comment: Using an array, or array comparison, in an `if` statement can raise this error.  `array<np.pi` will create a boolean array.  There's no implied `for` in a python `if`.  The solution depends on your desired logic - `any` or `all` can reduce the multiple booleans to one, or you may need to put the `if` inside a loop (or do some sort of array masking).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with  'where'

```
for i in range(0, int(t_total/h_passo), 1):
        TH_IT = TH_IT + ( h_passo*OM_IT )
        OM_IT = OM_IT + (h_passo/28)*(forca_teta(TH_IT, c_1, c_2) - 10*OM_IT)

        TH_IT[np.where(TH_IT <= -np.pi)] += 2*np.pi
        TH_IT[np.where(TH_IT > np.pi)] -= 2*np.pi
```